# How does jQuery/Javasscript handle this method invocation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given that only the first argument for `$.get` is mandatory:

```
$.get(URL,data,function(data,status,xhr),dataType)
```

How does jQuery/Javascript map the given arguments to the correct declared arguments in these two examples?

```
$.get("test.php", { name:"Donald", town:"Ducktown" });

$.get("test.php", function(data){
  alert("Data: " + data);
});
```

from http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_get.asp

In Python, you would have to call parameters by name if you skip the order. But how does jQuery handle it?

Comment: Because you can check the types of parameters?

Comment: Please use the jQuery API and not w3schools!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how does jQuery handle it?

Just take a look at [the code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/0d68b7877f761264bfe4950e4df156b854925a6b/src/ajax.js#L779):

```
jQuery[ "get" ] = function( url, data, callback, type ) {
    // shift arguments if data argument was omitted
    if ( jQuery.isFunction( data ) ) {
        type = type || callback;
        callback = data;
        data = undefined;
    }

    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "get",
        dataType: type,
        data: data,
        success: callback
    });
};
```

Comment: This is enlightening. I was thinking of signature pattern matching and overloaded methods in JS itself, whereas the jQuery authors have decided to do this explicitly for some reason.

Comment: @aitchnyu: There are no signatures in JS (other than the length of the formal parameters list). If you wanted to do anything with types, you'll have to do it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

it verifies the typing of parameters and accordingly it performs the actions.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, there are two things to make this possible: the `arguments` array-like object and the `typeof` operator. All functions have an array-like object named `arguments`. You can access all arguments passed to the function through it, even if they weren't named in the parameter list. Secondly, you can use the `typeof` operator to determine what type an argument is (`object`, `function`, `string`, etc). So, jQuery detects all the arguments using the `arguments` array, and then determines which are which using `typeof`.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Bergi's answer:

and `isFunction()` looks like:

```
isFunction: function( obj ) {
        return jQuery.type(obj) === "function";
    }
```

and to expand,  `jQuery.type()` looks like:

```
type: function( obj ) {
        if ( obj == null ) {
            return String( obj );
        }
        return typeof obj === "object" || typeof obj === "function" ?
            class2type[ core_toString.call(obj) ] || "object" :
            typeof obj;
    }
```

You can check the most recent jquery source [here](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js)